# Is my approach to bubble sort correct?

Tags: c#

Following is bubble sorting code.

I tried bubble sort after reading theory. Please let me know if my solution is correct and if so anyway I can make it more efficient?

```
 static int[] BubbleSort(int[] arr)
        {
            int count = arr.Length;

            while (count > 0)
            {
                int swapCount = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < count - 1; y++)
                {   
                    if (arr[y] > arr[y + 1])
                    {
                        swapCount++;
                        var temp = arr[y];
                        arr[y] = arr[y + 1];
                        arr[y + 1] = temp;

                    }
                }
                if (swapCount == 0)
                    return arr;
                count--;
            }

            return arr;
        }
```

Comment: *"let me know if my solution is correct"* - it is up to you to determine if it is correct or not, preferably with automated unit tests. If it is not correct, it does not belong on Code Review.

Comment: Hi, The code is running properly. My question was if the code is correct with the context to bubble sorting algorithm in mind.

Comment: Does it appear to produce the correct output when running tests? Code can run yet be completely faulty.

Comment: _"Can I make it more efficient?"_ - the biggest gain is to use a more efficient algorithm.  Bubble sort has notoriously poor average and worst-case performance.

Comment: Are you looking for tiny tricks like this:`(arr[y], arr[y+1]) = (arr[y + 1], arr[y]);` to avoid the usage of a `temp` variable?

Comment: @Mast Hi Mast, yes it is giving correct outputs :)

Comment: @TobySpeight I see, Thanks a lot for your reply. I will read about more efficient algos. :)

Comment: @PeterCsala Hi yes, Please let me know where I can learn more such tricks to reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show you how you can setup an environment where you can safely experiment with optimisation probes. I'll use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) for this purpose, which might seem an overkill for this simple use case. But it demonstrates the basic ideas.

So, let's create a simple console app, with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<BubbleSortExperiment>();
    }
}
```

Now, let's create the `BubbleSortExperiment` class:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[ShortRunJob]    
public class BubbleSortExperiment
{
    int[] array;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    [Params(500, 1000, 1500)]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {    
        array = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void WhileWhileTemp() => BubbleSortWhileWhileTemp(array.ToArray());

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public void WhileForTemp() => BubbleSortWhileForTemp(array.ToArray());

    [Benchmark]
    public void WhileForTuple() => BubbleSortWhileForTuple(array.ToArray());

    [Benchmark]
    public void ForForTuple() => BubbleSortForForTuple(array.ToArray());

    [Benchmark]
    public void ForForTemp() => BubbleSortForForTemp(array.ToArray());

    [Benchmark]
    public void ForWhileTemp() => BubbleSortForWhileTemp(array.ToArray());

    [Benchmark]
    public void ForWhileTuple() => BubbleSortForWhileTuple(array.ToArray());

    public int[] BubbleSortWhileForTemp(int[] arr)
    {
        int count = arr.Length;

        while (count > 0)
        {
            int swapCount = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < count - 1; y++)
            {
                if (arr[y] > arr[y + 1])
                {
                    var temp = arr[y];
                    arr[y] = arr[y + 1];
                    arr[y + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            if (swapCount == 0)
                return arr;
            count--;
        }

        return arr;
    }

    //...
    
    public int[] BubbleSortForForTuple(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int count = arr.Length; count > 0; count--)
        {
            int swapCount = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < count - 1; y++)
            {
                if (arr[y] > arr[y + 1])
                {
                    swapCount++;
                    (arr[y], arr[y + 1]) = (arr[y + 1], arr[y]);
                }
            }
            if (swapCount == 0)
                return arr;
        }

        return arr;
    }
}
```

- `MemoryDiagnoser` allows us to measure memory allocation and GC times.

  - Most of the variables are allocated on a stack, so in this particular case this will not give us too much valuable information
- `Length` it allows us to run the experiments with different values

  - In our case this means that the to be sorted array's length is 500, 1000 or 1500
- `Setup`: creates an array with the specified length and then we are shuffling its elements
- `.ToArray`: copies the original `array`, so each and every benchmark will run against the same dataset
- `[Benchmark]` this attribute depicts the different probes
- `[Benchmark(Baseline = true)]`: specifies which probe is the baseline << against which the other probes are compared

For the sake of demonstration I've created several probes where I used `for` or `while` for inner or outer loops. I've also change the `temp` variable to tuple in some probes.

Here are the results:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H1419) [Darwin 19.6.0]
Intel Core i9-9980HK CPU 2.40GHz, 1 CPU, 16 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.402
  [Host]   : .NET 5.0.11 (5.0.1121.47308), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  ShortRun : .NET 5.0.11 (5.0.1121.47308), X64 RyuJIT

Job=ShortRun  IterationCount=3  LaunchCount=1  
WarmupCount=3  

|         Method | Length |           Mean |         Error |       StdDev |  Ratio | RatioSD |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
|--------------- |------- |---------------:|--------------:|-------------:|-------:|--------:|-------:|----------:|
| WhileWhileTemp |    500 |   167,910.5 ns |  63,281.94 ns |  3,468.70 ns | 257.04 |    5.25 |      - |      2 KB |
|   WhileForTemp |    500 |       653.3 ns |      23.83 ns |      1.31 ns |   1.00 |    0.00 | 0.2413 |      2 KB |
|  WhileForTuple |    500 |   164,168.9 ns | 109,913.01 ns |  6,024.70 ns | 251.30 |    8.75 |      - |      2 KB |
|    ForForTuple |    500 |   166,614.4 ns |  57,209.60 ns |  3,135.85 ns | 255.06 |    5.00 |      - |      2 KB |
|     ForForTemp |    500 |   163,877.6 ns |  83,371.18 ns |  4,569.86 ns | 250.87 |    7.50 |      - |      2 KB |
|   ForWhileTemp |    500 |   162,630.7 ns | 116,827.12 ns |  6,403.69 ns | 248.95 |    9.48 |      - |      2 KB |
|  ForWhileTuple |    500 |   167,843.9 ns |  10,366.49 ns |    568.22 ns | 256.94 |    1.09 |      - |      2 KB |
|                |        |                |               |              |        |         |        |           |
| WhileWhileTemp |   1000 |   606,767.4 ns | 209,931.79 ns | 11,507.07 ns | 479.10 |   28.97 |      - |      4 KB |
|   WhileForTemp |   1000 |     1,268.6 ns |     975.12 ns |     53.45 ns |   1.00 |    0.00 | 0.4807 |      4 KB |
|  WhileForTuple |   1000 |   571,378.7 ns | 318,583.91 ns | 17,462.66 ns | 450.93 |   22.99 |      - |      4 KB |
|    ForForTuple |   1000 |   599,922.2 ns | 516,351.81 ns | 28,302.98 ns | 473.16 |   21.59 |      - |      4 KB |
|     ForForTemp |   1000 |   579,985.4 ns | 275,509.73 ns | 15,101.62 ns | 457.97 |   29.01 |      - |      4 KB |
|   ForWhileTemp |   1000 |   626,296.2 ns |  46,020.80 ns |  2,522.56 ns | 494.31 |   22.15 |      - |      4 KB |
|  ForWhileTuple |   1000 |   654,724.1 ns | 305,874.18 ns | 16,766.00 ns | 516.39 |   12.18 |      - |      4 KB |
|                |        |                |               |              |        |         |        |           |
| WhileWhileTemp |   1500 | 1,286,912.4 ns | 350,886.64 ns | 19,233.28 ns | 681.36 |   16.21 |      - |      6 KB |
|   WhileForTemp |   1500 |     1,889.1 ns |     527.12 ns |     28.89 ns |   1.00 |    0.00 | 0.7172 |      6 KB |
|  WhileForTuple |   1500 | 1,264,461.8 ns |  61,117.64 ns |  3,350.06 ns | 669.45 |    9.78 |      - |      6 KB |
|    ForForTuple |   1500 | 1,189,902.7 ns | 115,899.43 ns |  6,352.84 ns | 629.98 |   10.63 |      - |      6 KB |
|     ForForTemp |   1500 | 1,282,977.9 ns | 560,781.86 ns | 30,738.35 ns | 679.09 |    5.92 |      - |      6 KB |
|   ForWhileTemp |   1500 | 1,293,583.1 ns | 604,180.28 ns | 33,117.16 ns | 684.70 |    8.00 |      - |      6 KB |
```

| Method | Length | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WhileWhileTemp | 500 | 167,910.5 ns | 63,281.94 ns | 3,468.70 ns | 257.04 | 5.25 | - | 2 KB |
| WhileForTemp | 500 | 653.3 ns | 23.83 ns | 1.31 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.2413 | 2 KB |
| WhileForTuple | 500 | 164,168.9 ns | 109,913.01 ns | 6,024.70 ns | 251.30 | 8.75 | - | 2 KB |
| ForForTuple | 500 | 166,614.4 ns | 57,209.60 ns | 3,135.85 ns | 255.06 | 5.00 | - | 2 KB |
| ForForTemp | 500 | 163,877.6 ns | 83,371.18 ns | 4,569.86 ns | 250.87 | 7.50 | - | 2 KB |
| ForWhileTemp | 500 | 162,630.7 ns | 116,827.12 ns | 6,403.69 ns | 248.95 | 9.48 | - | 2 KB |
| ForWhileTuple | 500 | 167,843.9 ns | 10,366.49 ns | 568.22 ns | 256.94 | 1.09 | - | 2 KB |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| WhileWhileTemp | 1000 | 606,767.4 ns | 209,931.79 ns | 11,507.07 ns | 479.10 | 28.97 | - | 4 KB |
| WhileForTemp | 1000 | 1,268.6 ns | 975.12 ns | 53.45 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.4807 | 4 KB |
| WhileForTuple | 1000 | 571,378.7 ns | 318,583.91 ns | 17,462.66 ns | 450.93 | 22.99 | - | 4 KB |
| ForForTuple | 1000 | 599,922.2 ns | 516,351.81 ns | 28,302.98 ns | 473.16 | 21.59 | - | 4 KB |
| ForForTemp | 1000 | 579,985.4 ns | 275,509.73 ns | 15,101.62 ns | 457.97 | 29.01 | - | 4 KB |
| ForWhileTemp | 1000 | 626,296.2 ns | 46,020.80 ns | 2,522.56 ns | 494.31 | 22.15 | - | 4 KB |
| ForWhileTuple | 1000 | 654,724.1 ns | 305,874.18 ns | 16,766.00 ns | 516.39 | 12.18 | - | 4 KB |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| WhileWhileTemp | 1500 | 1,286,912.4 ns | 350,886.64 ns | 19,233.28 ns | 681.36 | 16.21 | - | 6 KB |
| WhileForTemp | 1500 | 1,889.1 ns | 527.12 ns | 28.89 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.7172 | 6 KB |
| WhileForTuple | 1500 | 1,264,461.8 ns | 61,117.64 ns | 3,350.06 ns | 669.45 | 9.78 | - | 6 KB |
| ForForTuple | 1500 | 1,189,902.7 ns | 115,899.43 ns | 6,352.84 ns | 629.98 | 10.63 | - | 6 KB |
| ForForTemp | 1500 | 1,282,977.9 ns | 560,781.86 ns | 30,738.35 ns | 679.09 | 5.92 | - | 6 KB |
| ForWhileTemp | 1500 | 1,293,583.1 ns | 604,180.28 ns | 33,117.16 ns | 684.70 | 8.00 | - | 6 KB |

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much, Toby. This is a really useful thing. Many thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @Saurabh It was me, Peter, who posted this. Tody just fixed something on the formatting. I'm glad that you have found it useful.